# ACEExpandableTableViewDelegate does not work in swift

Tags: swift, protocols

I write like this:

```
class XXXViewController: UITableViewController, ACEExpandableTableViewDelegate{}
```

and the Xcode said :

> type 'XXXViewController' does not conform to protocol
>   ACEExpandableTableViewDelegate

I have the bridge header file and imported "ACEExpandableTextCell.h", what should I do , do I miss something, someone help me please.

By the way, I use CocoaPods to install ACEExpandableTextCell.

Answer (score 0):

The error is just saying that you haven't implemented all mandatory methdods of `ACEExpandableTableViewDelegate` protocol in your `XXXViewController`.

Comment: I implemented both of them, but it still does not work.

Comment: Ok. You need to post more code, otherwise I can't help you.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/HongliYu/374c567c0e42e6be9a4a
And when I replace ACEExpandableTableViewDelegate with SampleProtocol, everything goes well, why?

Comment: I found that. If a method declared in Objective-C with a NSString Parameter, the swift code should use String, but the UITableView and NSIndexPath stay the same! If use NSString, it's another method

Answer (score 0):

### func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
              updatedText text: String,
         atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)

Change NSString to String ,UITableView and NSIndexPath stay the same, or it will be a new method